# Is it possible to change the overall language of a screen reader?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm refactoring a web app so that it's accessible for screen readers. The web application that I'm working on is in the Dutch language. The aria-labels are in Dutch as well, and are performing as I expect. Still, when tabbing trough the page the screen reader says: 'Navigation, list with 4 items'. Is it possible at all to change that (default reading the elements in EN) to dutch?

I set the HTML language attribute to Dutch
`<html lang="nl">`

But the screenreader (in Dutch / Google's Dutch voice) reads the elements as 'navigation, list with 4 items'.

Is there any possibility to change this default behaviour to go all Dutch? I'm using the ChromeVox plugin as screen reader. Is this a screen reader specific problem, or can it be solved in the code?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ChromeVox is speaking the element descriptions (and counts) in your operating system's language.

I would expect it to say "Navigation, list with 4 items" on my English system and then speak the labels in the language you specified (assuming you had the language packs and/or the screen reader did a good job of announcing on its own).

> Is there any possibility to change this default behaviour to go all Dutch?

Yes, change your operating system language to Dutch.

ChromeVox is not a screen reader in common use. It is primarily used for testing and does not do a good job of representing how (what I will call) true screen readers operate. I suggest you also try NVDA, VoiceOver, JAWS, Narrator, etc., with the Dutch language packs, *change your system language*, and then give it a go.

> Is this a screen reader specific problem, or can it be solved in the code?

Code alone will not do what you are asking.

**References**

When you get it sorted, here are some things you can expect just from using the `lang` attribute on the `<html>` element:

- VoiceOver on iOS uses the attribute to auto-switche voices.
- VoiceOver can speak a particular language using a different accent when specified.
- Leaving out the lang attribute may require the user to manually switch to the correct language for proper pronunciation.
- JAWS uses it to load the correct phonetic engine / phonologic dictionary — Handy for sites with multiple languages.
- NVDA (Windows) uses it in the same way as VoiceOver and JAWS.
- When used in HTML that is used to form an ePub or Apple iBooks document, it affects how VoiceOver will read the book.

I have some other information gathered here: http://adrianroselli.com/2015/01/on-use-of-lang-attribute.html

I also have a couple videos showing how a screen reader without the language packs might try to pronounce content it thinks is in a different language: http://adrianroselli.com/2017/03/slides-from-roledrinks-at-csun.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your extensive answer! Changing my OS language did do it indeed. Will also look in to the other screen readers you've recommended. I'll look it up, but what screen reader can you recommend for Mac users? Is VoiceOver from Mac commonly used?

Comment: VoiceOver is *the* screen reader on a Mac (and iOS). So yep, that is ideal. On Windows, NVDA is free and JAWS has a demo mode. Narrator comes built into Windows, but it is still finding its legs.